# Position of layers in ipyleaflet

Tags: leaflet, ipywidgets, ipyleaflet

With `ipyleaflet`, I am creating a map to which I add a `DrawControl`.

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, GeoJSON, DrawControl

m = Map(center=(40.730610, -73.935242), zoom=10)
draw_control = DrawControl(polyline={}, circlemarker={})
draw_control.rectangle = { 'shapeOptions': {"fillColor": "#ffab71"}}
m.add(draw_control)
m
```

Now, with `DrawControl`, I am creating polygons over the map.

Next, I add a GeoJSON layer to the map.

```
ny_poly= [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-74.0479, 40.6839],
                    [-73.9696, 40.6807],
                    [-73.9911, 40.6413],
                    [-74.0479, 40.6839]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {"name": "Polygon 1"}
    }]

geojson_layer1 = GeoJSON(data=ny_poly[0], style={"color": "red", "opacity": 1, "fillOpacity": 1})
m.add(geojson_layer1)
```

How can I ensure that the GeoJSON polygon is shown on top of the basemap, but below the polygons drawn with `DrawControl`?

I have seen other people using `m.panes` or playing with the order in the `m.layers` tuple but since I am working with DrawContorl, I cannot manage to make it work. See the image, how the red polygon is on top of the orange one.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Some references to similar solutions [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/993) and [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/843)